# webclient.openread() URI Format issue

Tags: asp.net, webclient

I am trying to send the uri from a textbox to weblclient instance. The issue is that if I send www.stackoverflow.com it throws the format exception. how to fix this issue? I can't attack the http:// because if the user pastes the correct format then the dynamically attached bit will cause problem.

```
 protected void TextBoxUrl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        doc.Load(wc.OpenRead(TextBoxUrl.Text),Encoding .UTF8 );

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

First move your code out of TextChanged or it will fire for every character entered.

Second, you will have to write a parsing routine of what is entered by the user. You can always check if TextBoxUrl.Text.StartsWith("http") and if it doesn't add it to the beginning of the string.

I would instead recommend something a bit better like using System.Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(TextBoxUrl.Text). If it passes then call your Load method, otherwise have them fix it OR add the "http" etc.

Comment: Ok thanks. Actually My concern was because of webrequest.Create() method. It does not throw execption on the above string. and as far the textchanged event it is different slightly than in windowsform. it fires when the mouse is clicked outside. anyway still nice solution.

Comment: yeah there's probably a different implementation for the HtmlAgilityPack than WebRequest I'm guessing i.e WebRequest is more forgiving perhaps =)